# LDAP bind with Zenoss 3

Tags: zenoss

Any hints to allow Zenoss 3 to authenticate via LDAP?

Comment: This belongs on serverfault. Voting to close/move.

Answer (score 1):

I have it working.  Have you see the Howto (referenced in my hints & tips following)??
You may have issues with the python-ldap plugin - I have needed to recompile this each time Zenoss has upgraded - including going to 3.0.2.  I wrote some hints here - http://community.zenoss.org/message/43170#43170

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://nathaniel.themccallums.org/2008/03/13/ldapactivedirectory-authorizationauthentication-and-zenoss/

then tell us where you had a problem.